# Docker: how to change startup arguments for a container that's already been created and runs at server startup?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-18.04

Got a Docker container that runs at startup and needs to have this added to the startup arguments:

```
 --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

I'm not readily seeing where to change the startup args for containers that are already setup and going. How would this be added to an existing container?

Comment: if you mean you have the image, then you may use ENTRYPOINT & CMD to pass in your arguments in your docker file.

Comment: @ZarehKasparian in this case I installed an image a couple years ago that has been running on an Ubuntu 18.04 server pretty much on autopilot. I've run into some issues wherein I need to modify the way the container (image?) starts up insomuch that it can communicate with the host via `host.docker.internal` as per instructions to turn this feature on for newer Linux Docker releases (already on for other OSes). I'm not clear on how to modify this startup... Not familiar w/Docker nomenclature as I've a very "resistive" past in accepting Docker as an option in the stack, but had to in this case.